# ACF Flexible Content - Looping two layouts (parse error?)

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

Getting to grips with ACF and it's flexible content field.

I have two layouts as shown below but I can't seem to get the second part (image_block) working correctly as it keeps popping up with a (parse error) I'm probably missing something obvious but if anyone has some advice it would be very helpful.

```
<?php if( have_rows('content-h') ):?>

    <?php while ( have_rows('content-h') ) : the_row();?>

    <?php if( get_row_layout() == 'text_block' ):
            $title = get_sub_field('title');
            $description = get_sub_field('description');
            $subheading = get_sub_field('subheading');
            
        ?>

            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="section-title">
                    <span class="text-color"><?php echo $subheading; ?></span>
                    <h2 class="mt-3 content-title"><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <p><?php echo $description; ?></p>
            </div>

    <?php endif; ?>

    </div>

    <div class="row justify-content-center">
    
    <?php if( get_row_layout() == 'image_block' ):
            $image = get_sub_field('image');
            $title = get_sub_field('title');
            $description = get_sub_field('description');
            $link = get_sub_field('link');
            
            ?>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12">
                <div class="intro-item mb-5 mb-lg-0"> 
                    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt'] ?>" alt="" class="img-fluid w-100">
                    <h4 class="mt-4 mb-3"><?php echo $title; ?></h4>
                    <p><?php echo $description; ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Tried following this video but still can't figure it out as are code appears to be the same? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DGLrgXywU4k

Comment: Can you tell us the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endwhile' (T_ENDWHILE), expecting elseif (T_ELSEIF) or else (T_ELSE) or endif (T_ENDIF) in C:\xampp\htdocs\seff\wp-content\themes\SEFF\page-home.php on line 96

Comment: That's the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a straight PHP parsing error, nothing to do with ACF or flexible fields.

See the comment where I believe you are missing an endif. The best thing to do in these situations is to go through your code line by line noting where you are starting a conditional and whether you have ended it correctly (so the blocks are nested).

Also check that your HTML elements are formed correctly. There appears to be an extra closing div tag - see comments in the code.

```
<?php if( have_rows('content-h') ):?>

    <?php while ( have_rows('content-h') ) : the_row();?>

    <?php if( get_row_layout() == 'text_block' ):
            $title = get_sub_field('title');
            $description = get_sub_field('description');
            $subheading = get_sub_field('subheading');
            
        ?>

            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="section-title">
                    <span class="text-color"><?php echo $subheading; ?></span>
                    <h2 class="mt-3 content-title"><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <p><?php echo $description; ?></p>
            </div>

    <?php endif; ?>

    </div> <!-- THIS closing div tag seems to be spurious -->

    <div class="row justify-content-center">
    
    <?php if( get_row_layout() == 'image_block' ):
            $image = get_sub_field('image');
            $title = get_sub_field('title');
            $description = get_sub_field('description');
            $link = get_sub_field('link');
            
            ?>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12">
                <div class="intro-item mb-5 mb-lg-0"> 
                    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt'] ?>" alt="" class="img-fluid w-100">
                    <h4 class="mt-4 mb-3"><?php echo $title; ?></h4>
                    <p><?php echo $description; ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>

       <?php endif; //THIS IS WHAT NEEDS TO BE ADDED CHECK IT IS IN THE RIGHT PLACE ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! seems so obvious now that you have kindly pointed it out. The extra div is actually linked to a <div class="row align-items-center"> outside of the php loop above <?php if( have_rows('content-h') ):?> I just didn't have it shown here.